# Variable values become null after setted up in onStart

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I've tried to set some variable with `onStart()` method, but their value become null when it come to `onCreate()` method.

This is `onStart()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Query emailQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("emailUser").equalTo(emailUser);
    emailQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                fSaldo = (String) singleSnapshot.child("saldoUser").getValue();
                fHeaderName = (String) singleSnapshot.child("username").getValue();
                fHeaderMail = (String) singleSnapshot.child("emailUser").getValue();
                phone = (String) singleSnapshot.child("phone").getValue();

                Log.d("Cozmo", "Saldo: " + fSaldo); //output: not_null
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

and this is `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirebaseAuth fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
    emailUser = user.getEmail();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Log.d("Cozmo", "Saldo: " + fSaldo); //output is null
}
```

This is my full MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private String fSaldo, fHeaderName, fHeaderMail, phone;
    private String emailUser;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {...}
}
```

I dont understand these variable become null again, and it become null after line of `onDataChange()` method passed. Are there any solutions?

Comment: `onCreate` is always called before `onStart`, so naturally, the value `fSaldo` will be null there

Comment: calling Log.d("Cozmo", "Saldo: " + fSaldo) on your onCreate will be always null, as the data has not been fetched yet. You will need to make a callback when it finish fetching if you want to place a log there

Comment: @MikeM. so.. is it doesn't matter, if I process the data at onDataChange()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of conceptual things wrong with this code. 
First of all, `onCreate()` is called before `onStart()` that is, `onCreate()` is called first and then only `onStart()`.
Second, `fSaldo = (String) singleSnapshot.child("saldoUser").getValue();` is inside onDataChanged so we don't know when that method will be called and when that value will be set, it is asynchornous. But this doesn't matter because you need to fix the first error first.